# Need some help getting Apache 2.2.5 to register environmental variables (CentOS 6.10)

Tags: python-2.7, apache, centos, google-cloud-sdk

I've tried every solution I've found in the last two days on this and other sites. None work.

I'm trying to set two OS level environment variables/commands for the apache user account on centos 6.10. Apache version is 2.2.5. See final paragraph for why I'm having to do this. Alternative solutions are also welcome.

Specifically these commands/variables:

```
. /opt/rh/python27/enable
export set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python2
```

I have:
Put them in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and `/etc/init.d/httpd`

Tried various version of these commands
Switched apache to use bash, created `.bashrc` in `/var/www/`, gave apache ownership and set permissions correctly and put them in there. I realize this is bad practice, its a test server and I was out of other ideas.

I can't get them to persist beyond a single exec statement in php (where I still have to call both listed commands) or a single `su -s /bin/bash apache -c "[command]"` execution.

Does anyone know how to get these to persist for the apache user?

Why am I doing this?

I am doing this because Google Cloud Cloud SDK has PHP code that doesn't work so I'm left with either using CURL or passing exec statements, both of which require this environmental variable nonsense for the executing user. To run Google Cloud SDK commands you have to have version 2.7 of python installed, which you can't upgrade to on centos 6.10 without breaking the OS, unless you install it concurrently somewhere else per: http://jhurani.com/linux/2018/07/30/GCSDK-on-centos6.html doing that means I have to set whatever user account is executing code to use the new version of python. Which is apache in this case. Works fine on my normal user account, but I can't get the apache account to respect these changes beyond a single execution, even though everything I read says that it should.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for you time and any insight you'd care to share.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to export the variables in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

```
export mydocroot=/var/www/html
```

Then configure the Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot ${mydocroot}
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally restart the service

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

In addition, I found that you can also do it through the .httaccess file with [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) assuming that it's enabled on the website.

```
SetEnv SPECIAL_PATH /foo/bin
```

That's all you need to add the environment variable into the .htaccess file